# Folder permission error on using / installing XenForo 2.1.4

Tags: php, permissions, chmod, chown, xenforo

Hi StackOverflow community,
Recently I migrated my website from a server to another. The OS and the web server software are the same on both servers (Apache HTTPD on CentOS 7)
When I transferred the forum I encountered a problem: in the admin panel come up an error:

```
    The following errors occurred while verifying that your server still meets the minimum requirements:
The directory /var/www/html/forum-old/data must be writable. Please change the permissions on this directory to be world writable (chmod 0777). If the directory does not exist, please create it.
The directory /var/www/html/forum-old/internal_data must be writable. Please change the permissions on this directory to be world writable (chmod 0777). If the directory does not exist, please create it.
```

I tried all. I tried to give 0777 permission on data/ and internal_data/. I also tried to give the permission recursively ( -R in chmod ). I also tried to give the chown recursively to Apache to the /var/www/html/forum

And I also tried to install a fresh installation of XenForo and it gives me the same error

I hope to find a solution.
Bye

Comment: Apache wants `.../forum-old/...` to be writable, not `.../forum/...`

Comment: Ok. It was a post error. I also tried that

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use on all my Xenforo 2 sites, it was shared at some point on the Xenforo forums.

```
find /var/www/html/forum-old/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644
find /var/www/html/forum-old/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755
find /var/www/html/forum-old/internal_data/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0777
find /var/www/html/forum-old/data/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0777
find /var/www/html/forum-old/internal_data/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0777
find /var/www/html/forum-old/data/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0777
chmod 0755 /var/www/html/forum-old
```

Your error shows: `/var/www/html/forum-old`

If you're now serving out of `/var/www/html/forum` you need to update the home directory in the xenforo settings so it knows to use the new folder